Does it matter where I'm buying stocks, or only where I'm selling them? (from tax perspective)
I'm a Polish citizen but I live in Thailand since a few years, and currently I have tax residency only in Thailand. I've been buying some S&P 500 stocks here on an international stock exchange, using a Thai broker (so from my account in Thai currency into a USD account of a broker).
I don't plan to live here forever, so let's say that in 10 years I will be living in Poland and be a tax resident there. I will sell my stocks with a gain and will have to pay capital gains taxes.
In this case, does it matter that I've been buying stocks in another country throughout those 10 years, or it doesn't matter at all and I will pay taxes only in Poland? Is it better to send my money to a Polish bank account and keep buying stocks from there instead?

I would guess that what matters first is where you sell and realize the profit. Though some governments may tax their citizen's incomes no matter where the profit occurred.
